# Pocket-size keyboard for a programmer

Tags: keyboards, osx

I'm looking for pocket-size keyboard, so it can be carried between work on daily basis without additional headache. Can either be wireless or wired.

It should work without any lag or known problems (such as easily mistaking <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> - and all my tabs are gone). It should be compatible with OS X.

It can be either foldable, rollable, invisible or similar to not take much space when travelling, so I'm not sure which one you can recommend?

Comment: In my experience, "pocket size" and "programmer" are mutually-exclusive requirements.

Comment: See my [answer](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/165/60) for a good customizable keyboard. It is on the heavy side, but I love mine. Keep in mind that this might be bigger than you were looking for, hence this is only a comment.

Comment: I ordered a [Text Blade](https://waytools.com/) quite some time ago on a kickstarter type thing. Hopefully will be shipping mid-October. It looks like it has the potential to be a comfortable and portable keyboard.

Comment: I have two Microsoft Natural 4000s, both at home and at work. Solves the problem.

Comment: I don't like those Ergonomic Keyboards, they're just slowing my typing and they're way too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't own one of these, so I can't say how I feel about it, but it seems interesting.

This is a [laser keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PLLXGJ0) which is said to be "fast and accurate".

### Pros

- Supports everything, from iOS, to Android, to Windows XP - 10, and Mac OSX
- Is said to be "accurate" on Amazon page.
- Has bluetooth
- Supports USB
- Only weighs 5.6 ounces

### Cons

- Only registers ~7 chars/second. If you can type that fast, this is a con.
- Quoting an amazon review

  > must be used on a flat surface that is non-reflective and uniform in color.
- Quoting the same review

  > laser keyboard is more difficult to see during the day than is a normal keyboard. It's bright enough to see, but in strong light, the edges are a bit hazy and when the product is new to you, this will slow you down.

[image: Customer Image]
[image: Amazon Image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have large pockets (not necessarily cargo pants size), the Poker ][ is a very nice pocket-size board.  Mine has an aftermarket aluminum case, which means it's a very tight fit in my pants.

[image: This would've fit much better had I removed my wallet and keys first]

Vortex has since discontinued the Poker ][ in favor of the Pok3r, which comes with a stock aluminium case and has a different default fn-layer mapping.  Other 60% keyboards should be about the same size as the Poker series.

If you're looking for something even smaller and are willing to live with using the numbers from a function layer, the JD 40 (since discontinued, or at least no longer listed on the manufacturer's website, https://www.crtralt.io) was a good bet.

Assuming you do not mind both a the 40% size and an ortholinear layout, the [Planck](http://ortholinearkeyboards.com/planck) is your way to go.  [Its manufacturer](http://ortholinearkeyboards.com/) also makes parts for the [Atomic](http://ortholinearkeyboards.com/atomic), which is an ortholinear 60% keyboard that you get to assemble yourself.

Finally, the [TypeMatrix 2030](http://www.typematrix.com/2030/features.php) is deeper and maybe a bit wider than the other options, but is easily the thinnest of the bunch.  It's a 60% ortholinear keyboard with scissor switches (the others all use traditional mechanical switches).  It won't fit into any pockets (unless you count the font pocket of a hoodie sweatshirt, but it will easily fit into a briefcase, backpack, or on top of a stack of books.