# Premium keyboard

Tags: keyboards, linux, ergonomics

I am a developer, and I can now afford to buy a good keyboard for work. What do you recommend for a good ergonomic keyboard preferable with media controls?

It does not need to be ergonomic. Looking cool would be nice, but not a big deal. Basically what keyboard do you recommend for a developer (Windows local machine, but [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) into Linux most of the time.)

It does not need to be portable, and there isn't much of a constraint cost. Mostly I am looking for something ergonomic.

Comment: Related: [Keyboard for programmers?](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/126/keyboard-for-programmers)

Comment: `What do you recommend for a good ergonomic keyboard preferable with media controls. Does not need to be ergonomic. ` Does it need to be ergonomic or not?

Comment: Do you want mechanical keys? Would you like the keyboard separated in the middle? Wireless preference? By cool looking, do you mean LED's and such?

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to try a new keyboard layout [Truly Ergonomic](https://www.trulyergonomic.com/) makes a mechanical keyboard that is structured oddly. It is suppose to be better for you than the standard keyboards (during long term use) and they have different key switch options. It should also be noted that this keyboard does not have a keypad, if you find yourself using the keypad a lot then it may not be a good choice. (Personally I did away with my keypad years ago, never used it in my development work and wasted desktop space).

[image: Ergonomic Layout]

Switch (key) types:

**SOFT TACTILE**

> These switches are quiet and provide a gentle tactile feedback
>   that helps you feel when each key registers, allowing you to use minimal force.

**CLICK TACTILE**

> These switches provide a light‑click‑sound feedback and a
>   gentle tactile feedback that helps you feel and hear when each key registers.

**FIRM TACTILE**

> These switches are quiet and provide a firm tactile feedback
>   that helps you feel when each key registers. If you have used Soft Tactile mechanical switches and find them too soft, these switches would be best.

**MEMBRANE**

> On membrane keyboards, the key passes through a plastic layer with electrical contacts and then through a hole to a second layer that interrupts a circuit to register the stroke. Pressing through these layers makes typing on a membrane feel like tapping your fingers on old, stale Jell-O.

*(Membrane is standard keyboard feel and the quote is a bit exaggerated but does explain it well. These keys are soft and have not tactical feedback.)*

References:

- [Mechanical](https://www.trulyergonomic.com/store/mechanical-keyswitches--cherry-mx-brown-red-blue-black-clear--truly-ergonomic-mechanical-keyboard)
- [Membrane](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/why-you-want-mechanical-keyboard,news-19706.html)

Note: There lots of different types I have listed some of the common types. Also if you are thinking about a mechanical keyboard please remember your coworkers and that typing can be quite loud with some switches (notably the click ones). Maybe ask them first if they are ok with a noisy keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

From what other people have told me, the [Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/b2m-00012) is one of the best keyboards that they have bought. This is a full sized keyboard, so it has a number pad and will not be as portable as a smaller keyboard. It does have media keys (play/pause, next, previous, and mute) as well.

There are a few additional features that this keyboard offers. There is a Zoom Slider in the middle of the keyboard. It also has customizable buttons that you can program to do tasks "like opening documents and replying to email messages".

I am sure that I have missed something about this keyboard as I do not own one. I do know however that this is a great keyboard. I have worked at a few different places in the tech industry and this is a popular keyboard among my co-workers.

[image: Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000]