# Quiet keyboard for typing, ideally with keys to the left of the main pad

Tags: keyboards

I'm looking to buy a keyboard. My main activities are typing text and programming, not gaming.

Must have:

- Basic **105-key** layout. Either UK or French will do. A US keyboard is no good because it has one less key on the main pad.
- Available for purchase in the EU. That should follow from the layout anyway.
- **Quiet**. It doesn't have to be absolutely silent, but I derive no satisfaction from hearing the click of a keyboard, only annoyance. Keyboards should be felt, not heard.
- USB.

Preferences:

- **Agreeable for typing**. I don't know how to describe this in technical terms. Unfortunately, where I live, very few shops have a selection of non-gamer keyboards to try out.
- Extra “multimedia” keys. Ideally, with some **keys to the left of the main pad**. (I wish the standard layout of keyboards wasn't so imbalanced with the right hand doing everything outside the main pad!)
- Available in white. When the sun shines on it, it does make a difference.

Do not care:

- Price isn't an object if the object is durable.

Do not want:

- Fancy blinkenlights and other gamerz stuff. Keyboard should be felt, not seen.
- Fancy ergonomic layouts. I'm not good at switching between keyboard shapes and I need to stay used to mainstream keyboards.
- Flat keyboards without any touch feedback.

Comment: Wanted to recommend A4Tech's KV-300H, but I forgot that Poland uses US layout :/ a great keyboard, but doesn't fit your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

It's really hard to find keyboard which meets all your requirements. So I will recommend you quite expensive keyboard but it will meet most of your requirements.

---

[**WASD V2 105-Key ISO Custom Mechanical Keyboard**](http://www.wasdkeyboards.com/index.php/products/mechanical-keyboard/wasd-v2-105-key-iso-custom-mechanical-keyboard.html) - **base cost $150**

It's customizable mechanical keyboard with 105-key layout. It provides buyer with many options which allows it to be the closer choice to your requirements.

**Layout:**

You can choose from French/UK and many other layouts. Additionally you can customize other keys.
[image: french layout]
[image: uk layout]

**Silence:**

You can choose between different types of Cherry MX switches and sound dampeners. I would recommend using **Cherry MX red switches** (+ $10) - it is most silent type of Cherry MX because of linear switch mechanism and softer spring than black ones. To make this construction even more silent you can add to it sound dampeners to keys but it is also quite expensive (+$25).

**Color:**

Unfortunately there is no possibility to order whole keyboard in white color but you can order it with white keys.
[image: whole keyboard]

**Cons**

- not avaliable in EU but it can be shipped to EU
- **price** (with **Cherry MX red** switches($10), **sound dampeners** ($25) and shipment to France (~$45) it is **~$230**)
- no additional keys on the left

---

I assume that 105-key layout is the most important requirement ? Because I would recommend some cheaper devices in 104-key layout like [Natec Medusa 2 White](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Natec-Medusa-International-Layout-Keyboard/dp/B00B1ACYYS/ref=sr_1_3?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1461242091&sr=1-3&keywords=natec%20medusa).

Comment: Another [answer](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/165/60) (mine) that recommends the same keyboard, but different layout.

Answer (score 1):

I recommending to you try the [Apple keyboards](http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MB110B/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-british) (works ok in Windows too). They coming in two versions (US or UK)

[image]
[image]

Pros:

- low profile keys, so:

  - it is an "typer's" keyboard (usable, but not the best for gaming)
  - silent, but with good "press feedback"
- USB connected (and contains 2 usb ports on both sides for connecting the mice)
- silver aluminum body (even better on the sunlight as white) with white keys
- you can buy it from any apple dealer in EU
- nice design (IMHO) :)

cons:

- no extra multimedia keys on the left side...
- in the function keys the primary symbols are the apple's multimedia functions, the f1..f12 is printed in small letters (they works as functions keys)
- price

Ps: Me using it 3+ years and i'm absolutely happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend Keychron keyboards. They are reasonably priced, have a range of different options (layouts and switch mechanisms), most are wireless with a battery charged via USB and can also be used as a wired keyboard. Build quality is excellent and first party accessories are available (carry cases, matching palm rests, etc) with basic accessories included in the box (such as Windows / Mac key caps).

Mine has LK Optical Red switches. If you type softly, it is completely silent. If you type aggressively you'll get complaints from next door. I didn't find it to hard to learn how to type gently but YMMV...

Their quietest switch is probably Cherry MX Red if you install an aftermarket mod to dampen the upstroke (I wouldn't worry about downstroke on any red switch). I would use these, except I've had problems with humidity and/or dust eventually causing the switch to malfunction. Optical switches are more resilient to harsh environments.

It has "Fancy blinkenlights", but some profiles are tasteful (e.g. white) and you can drop the brightness to zero. Check the manual to learn how to disable the light profile switch so it cannot be changed by accident. I started with white, but eventually switched to a rainbow layout - it's quicker to find my resting hand position by color instead of feeling for the F/K bumps.