# Best Mechanical Keyboard for £100($125/€118 - Cherry MX Brown/Red)

Tags: keyboards

I am in the market for a Mechanical Keyboard with a 10-key keypad. I am going to be using it for both work and gaming so I am looking at either a Cherry MX Red or Cherry MX Brown switch.

I have a strict budget of £100/$125/€118(so it can be anything under but not a penny over).

Given that I am spending this much money I want something that is going to last me a long time.

So far I have as follows:

Corsair K70 Lux Blue

SteelSeries Apex M500

Corsair Strafe MX Red

Corsair Strafe MX Brown

HyperX Alloy FPS

ASUS Strix Tactic Pro Gaming Keyboard

Logitech G610 Orion

I've been doing my reading a I've heard in some places, Logitech, Steelseries, ASUS, HyperX, and Corsair are good brands for mechanical keyboards.

In some places I've seen people saying that CoolerMaster, Deck, Ducky, Filco, KB Paradise, KUL, Leopold, WASD, and Varmilo are reputable brands. Out of this list the only brands that I know of are Filco and Cooler Master.

With that being said, what keyboards do you like out of this list/could add to this list that would fit my requirements?

Update: In thinking about it further, based on what I will be using it for, I think that a keyboard with a Cherry MX Brown switch will be the best way to go.

Comment: Have you looked at this [question](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/126/60)? This isn't a duplicate because your requirements are different, but you should be able to look at the answers there to see if any of them would work for you.

Comment: I had a look and most of them are outside of my price range. The sculpt ergonomic keyboard from Microsoft is good but we are talking about Mechanical keyboads here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that question was about mechanical keyboards. I thought we had a good question about those. I will keep looking.

Answer (score 2):

**Check out [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/wiki/uk_shopping_guide) and also [mechanical keyboard reseller spreadsheet for UK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A_0FPRfpcthe2szdHG-kympwm_uROKWtIzRZKuPNuZI/htmlview), it has most keyboards available in the UK with their respective prices and where to get them.**

For price range <£100, Cherry MX Red Brown, ISO layout

- Ducky One series, available in backlit and non-backlit (£75.00 - £99.99)
- Cooler Master Quickfire series, (£65.00 - £85.00)
- Cooler Master Masterkeys pro L / M (£79.99 - £96.99)
- Logitech G610, (£74.99 - £99.99)

Comment: Funnily enough the G610 is on my list of candidates at the moment! I should also point out that I have decided that I want to go with a keyboard that has a Cherry MX Brown switch.

Comment: So far my list of candidates is as follows: Cooler Master Master Keys,
Cooler Master Quickfire TK,
Logitech G610 Orion Brown,
and the Corsair Strafe.
Right now, my gut is telling me either the Corsair Strafe or the Logitech G610 Orion Brown. With that said the scores between these 4 is a different of about a point (out of 10) as such it's still a close call.

Comment: Good thing that keyboards with brown switches are the most available then. At that point it all just comes down to the form factor and design, are you looking for full size, tenkeyless, or maybe TK (special hybrid  between tenkeyless and full size found on CM Masterkeys pro M and quickfire TK)? What color lighting would you want to fit your build? Is there a brand that you like better? Coz all these keyboards offer pretty much the same functionalities and software,

Comment: For me, I need a full size keyboard (as that will have the 10 key keypad. I need something that's durable. For me, the coloured lighting is a nice to have (if it's within the price limit that I set). As long as the colour of the lighting is not pink then we are good to go.

Comment: FYI the TK form factor allows you to toggle between arrow keys + pgup down prtsc cluster and a 10 keypad, if you have limited desk space and would like to save some space. Otherwise I would recommend G610 or CM Master Keys, I don't particularly like the plastic Corsair used on their strafe keyboards, feels somewhat hollow compared to the others, Logitech and CM are usually pretty reliable, but honestly you can't go wrong with any of them, I'd just get whichever one is on sale

Comment: I have checked what they look like and I like having dedicated arrow buttons (instead of having them tucked into the 10-key keypad). I also like having separate buttons for page up, page down etc. For me, space is not the issue at all as the current keyboard I have is almost the same width as the candidates. If there is lighting, I would like to be able to change the brightness of the lighting. So that narrows it down a little more!

Comment: And then there were three: The Cooler Master Master Keys Pro L, the Logitech G610 Orion Brown and the Corsair Strafe! The G610 has dedicated multimedia buttons(instead of being on F Keys). On the other hand the only deal breaker is that the Cooler Master which has a 6 key rollover but switches to N key rollover when more than 6 keys are pressed (according to cooler master's website). Other than that I cannot pick them apart!

Comment: 6 key rollover is usually more than enough for any gaming usages, I have yet to have problems on my filco (6kro), as I believe the 6 key only applies to alphabets, modifiers like ctrl alt are treated separatedly. I think G610 is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I personally have the **Ducky Zero** with brown switches and the build quality is very solid. It does not have any fancy features (the only one i really miss is start/stop buttons for media players), but apart from that it is very good.

The price should be around 100 € - in any case less than your maximum amount.

Comment: I had a look around and Ducky Zero with brown is not available in the UK. It has to be available in the UK with a UK keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

The search is over. After much deliberation, I ended up going with the Logitech G610 Orion Brown. The Corsair Strafe was a good keyboard and had nice red backlighting but the keys seemed to jut out a little more than the Logitech one.

Additionally I know that Logitech make good keyboards so I can relax knowing that Logitech is brand that I can trust.

If anyone is interested I will write back with my opinion in terms of what my experience was like using it.

edit: Thanks to everyone for their help and suggestions.